# Understanding definition of minimax value

Tags: artificial-intelligence, definition

In Russell and Norvig, third edition, they give the following definition of the minimax value of a node in a game tree (zero-sum, perfect information, deterministic)

> The minimax value of a node is the utility (for MAX) of being in the corresponding state, *assuming that both players play optimally* from there to the end of the game.

Only thing is, that in their setup of a game, the utility of a node is only defined for *terminal* nodes, so how should one understand the utility of a general node ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Utility is defined for non-terminal nodes.  It's that for terminal nodes, utility is estimated by some external heuristic (which they call UTILITY), but for non-terminal nodes utility is computed by the minimax algorithm.  The minimax value (or utility) of a non-terminal node is either the maximum or the minimum of the minimax values of its children (depending on whose move it is).  The minimax value of the root will be the utility of the outcome you'll get to if both you and your opponent make optimal moves from there on out.

There's a worked-out example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Example_2) that should make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Each node should represent a gamestate, given a set of actions by each player.

Utility should be defined for each gamestate, and thereby, each node. It should represent how favorable a gamestate is for a player.

Minimax tree nodes are computed *every other layer*. That is to say, I don't evaluate the state of the game directly after my move, but instead after each time my opponent(s) make a move.

For a two player game:

I have X possible moves.

For each of my X possible moves, there is a gamestate. We do not need the utility of these gamestates.

For each of those X gamestates, my opponent has Y possible moves.

For each of those Y possible moves, there is another gamestate. We need the utilities of these gamestates.